# Matrix A with real eigenvalues such that $A^2$ is similar to $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a matrix with real eigenvalues such that $A^2$ is similiar to A.
What are the possible eigenvalues of $A$?

I know that similiar matrix have the same eigenvalues, and also, eigenvalue square is the eigenvalue of $A^2$

So i would have: $\lambda$v = $\lambda^2$v = $A^2$v = $A$v

I don't know what to do after, i'm done???

Comment: Yes, you are done. Since $v\neq 0$ and $(\lambda^2-\lambda)v=0$ you can could - what?

Comment: With that i conclude that $\lambda^2$=$\lambda$, and then $\lambda$ are 1, -1 or 0, right?

Comment: @Vityôk Well, $\;-1\;$ is not a solution to $\;\lambda^2=\lambda\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio $A^2$ is not equal to $A$, it is only similar to it.

Comment: You are right @DonAntonio, thanks!

Comment: @Vityôk No, it is not true that $\lambda v = \lambda^2 v$. $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but not necessarily with the same eigenvector.

Comment: @MattSamuel I only referred to the comment above mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar matrices do have the same eigenvalues. If $u$ is an eigenvector, then
$$A^2u = \lambda^2 u$$
There is a matrix $P$ such that $PA^2P^{-1}=A$. Then
$$AP(u)=\lambda^2P(u)$$
so $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $P(u)$. We can iterate this: $\lambda^4$, $\lambda^8$, etc. are all eigenvalues of $A$. Since there are only finitely many, this must be a cycle. But this is only possible when the eigenvalues have absolute value $0$ or $1$, so they must be $0$, $1$, or $-1$.

Comment: "Since there are only finitely many, this must be a cycle." Yes they are finitely many but what has this to do with a cycle?